# Fourier transform of $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\mathsf{sinc}( x )} $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

I have to find inverse Fourier transform of 
\begin{align*}
F(\omega)=e^{-\frac{\omega^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\mathsf{sinc}( \omega )} 
\end{align*}
I was wondering whether it exists maybe in a sense of distributions.

Using duality between Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform. We can ask what is Fourier transform of 
\begin{align*}
f(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\frac{1}{\mathsf{sinc}( x )} 
\end{align*}
and whether it exits?

Note, that the function $f(t)$  has vertical asymptots at for $x=n \pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$
\begin{align}
\mathsf{sinc}( x )=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}
\end{align}
equals $0$ at integer multiplies of $\pi$.
Is this a problem?

One way to look at the problem is find convolution of $\mathcal{F}(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}})$ and $\mathcal{F}(\frac{1}{\mathsf{sinc}( x )})$. However, this direction can be problematic since $\mathcal{F}(\frac{1}{\mathsf{sinc}( x )})$ might not exist.

Comment: The Fourier transform of a convolution is a product.  So what you are looking for is a convolution of the inverse Fourier transform of the first function (which will be a Gaussian also) and the inverse Fourier Transform of the reciprocal sinc.

Comment: Yes, good. But  what is the inverse Fourier of $\frac{1}{sinc}$?

Comment: Since 1/sinc is unbounded, I can't imagine it has one.  Is there some bound to address this issue?